# ReactJs onClick add className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, classname

I am new to reactjs.

So I have an issue. My className does not update when I trigger the onClick event. What might be cousing the problem?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Categorie extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {categorie: "oldClass"};
}

addClassName() {
    this.setState = ({categorie: "newClass"});
    console.log(this.state.categorie);
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className={this.state.categorie} onClick={this.addClassName.bind(this)}>
            <div className="categorieImgBlock">
               <img className="categorieImg" src={this.props.img}/>
            </div>
            <span className="categorieName">{this.props.name}</span>
            <span className="categorieCount">( {this.props.count} )</span>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a minor typo:

```
this.setState = ({categorie: "newClass"});
```

Shoud be:

```
this.setState({categorie: "newClass"});
```

Also `setState()` is asynchronous so your `console.log` statement right after it might not show you the actual new state, if you really want to do something after new state is set you should give it a callback function as 2nd argument.

```
this.setState({categorie: "newClass"}, () => console.log(this.state.categorie));
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` is a function that sets the state for you so that react can take to proper steps to handle an update. You need to call `this.setState` with a new object and it will map the object to you current state (the console log may not also work because `setState` is an asynchronous function).

```
addClassName() {
    this.setState({categorie: "newClass"});
    console.log(this.state.categorie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to `setState`. Should be function call.

```
addClassName() {
    this.setState({categorie: "newClass"}); // NB!
    console.log(this.state.categorie);
}
```